# I would like to obtain information from a text file and assign that information into class objects

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Why the compiler throw me error:invalid use of 'Student::Student'|

this is content file(ListOfStudent):1234 46567 
this is my code:

```
class Student
{string ML,MSV;
public:
    Student();
    Student(string ML,string MSV );
    ~Student();
    void Out();
};
int main()

{
    vector<Student>ListOfStudent;
    {
        ifstream inf("ListOfStudentFile");
        Student st;
        while(inf){
            string ML,MSV;
             inf>>ML>>MSV;
             st.Student(ML,MSV);
            ListOfStudent.push_back(st);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
Student::Student(string ML,string MSV)
{
    this->ML=ML;
    this->MSV=MSV;

}
```

Comment: Please convert your code to a [mcve] and post the complete error message from the  compiler.

Comment: @RSahu In what way is the question not an MCVE?

Comment: You can add the few missing pieces to make sure that the code can be compiled to produce the exact error you are seeing.

Comment: You cannot call the constructor via an instance. `st.Student(ML,MSV);` should be changed to `st = Student(ML,MSV);` or simpler `Student st(ML,MSV);`

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a constructor explicitely.
You should have written:

```
while(inf){
            string ML,MSV;
             inf>>ML>>MSV;
            ListOfStudent.push_back(Student(ML,MSV));
        }
```

Following Hemil's suggestion and if you are using C++ 11, you can avoid constructing a temporary, via direct passing of constructor's arguments like this:

```
while(inf){
            string ML,MSV;
             inf>>ML>>MSV;
            ListOfStudent.emplace_back(ML,MSV);
        }
```

For a simple struct like yours, it should not make any difference anyway, so use whatever you prefer.

Comment: The code is good but `Student(ML,MSV)` is an explicit constructor call isn't it?

Comment: The way Student is being constructed, emplace_back is the way to go I feel